# Wordpress upload media

Tags: wordpress, plugins, upload, media

I want to upload media to wordpress in my custom plugin with the function `media_handle_upload`.

Before passing the file to the function the object looks like this:

`constructorArray ( [name] => limit (2).jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpxBWMPN [error] => 0 [size] => 43734 )`

After callin `media_handle_upload`

```
$movefile = media_handle_upload($file, 0);
```

I get this error object.

`WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [upload_error] => Array ( [0] => File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini. ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )`

I was searching online for the solution. And there i got suggested that i have to change the post and upload size in `php.ini`. Is this file part of wordpress or part of my cpanel?

Are there other solutions to get this thing running?

Answer (score 0):

Got the resolution:

**DON'T** pass the file like this to the function:

```
media_handle_upload($_FILES('myFileUpload'), 0);
```

**RESOLUTION** just pass it as a string :)

```
media_handle_upload('myFileUpload', 0);
```